# Weblogic WebService with EJB

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

I am going to develop a webservice which will expose two operations. These operation will query/update data from database.

Please suggest do i use EJB for database operation and what advantage i will get?

or

in my webservice i use JPA directly like following, and create my entities and persist them

```
@PersistenceUnit private EntityManagerFactory emf;
@Resource
private UserTransaction utx;
```

Please answer with advantages/disadvantages.

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are valid and supported by Java EE, so this is only a *design* recommendation based on my experience:

Do never directly expose EJB operations as Web Services, it only increases runtime complexity. If you publish an EJB as a Web Service the container must still wrap it by using an internal *Web Services servlet* which (implicitly) tightly couples your WAR containing the internal Web Service mapping to your ejb-jar (depends on app server product). Furthermore, it's hard to debug in day-to-day operations.

My recommendation using only standard Java EE features without any additional libraries:

- POJO defines the Web Service interface, aka its operations (`@WebService` annotation). It delegates to a functional implementation. Let's call this POJO *WS-POJO*.

Two options to implement the functionality:

1. *WS-POJO* calls stateless Session Beans which provide the required functionality. Pro: All EJB features available (dependency injection, declarative transaction mgmt, etc.). Con: "Heavyweight"
2. *WS-POJO* calls custom POJOs following e.g. the *Command Pattern*. Pro: "Lightweight". Con: Dependency injection not possible; Entity Manager etc. to be passed.

Today, I'd go with option #1... my 2 cent

Comment: @Dear home, I getting 404 Error (Page Not Found) when calling webservice while exposing EJB as a Rest in weblogic; I have been added a class inherited from `Application` which annotated by **@ApplicationPath("/resources")** , and my web service class is a stateless which annotated by **@Path("/getdata")** and it includes a simple method annotated by **@GET @Path("/getaccount")** The URL I have used in Weblogic to call this webservice is: `http://localhost:7001/resources/getdata/getaccount` which results **Error 404--Not Found**